# why my application performance got increased while using appmetrics profiler in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am running my nodejs application in **production** mode. while doing load testing using jmeter(100 requests per second), my system cpu goes up to 100% and throughput started reducing from 125 to 96 and it keeps decreasing when test continues. so i have added **[appmetrics-dash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics-dash)** profiler in my application for cpu profiling. Below code has been added before creating and the server.

```
var dash = require('appmetrics-dash');  
dash.monitor();
```

while doing profiling to check the cpu by running the nodejs application in **production** mode with same load cpu was normal(even if it goes high also, becomes normal) and the  through was 185. so i don't have any idea that due to which profiler parameter performance increased. i want to use the same parameter in my application to increase the performance. please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not actually the case. Since the profiler further adds the load to the application, the observation that you have specified is somewhat falsey.

What happens when you profile with jmeter or with any other tool is, application first absorbs lot of resources but later it stabilizes. It is only after that point you can comment on any applications resource consumption. I believe that you would have added profiler when application would have stabilized.